# Java jframe use of functions of main

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have been coding for few days with swing, but im getting to a problem ...I have functions and variables from different classes that are set in the main class that runs the program and calls the jframe.The problem i have is how do i call the functions in the main class in the jframe code that is set as a new class named as

```
public class login_sistema extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

I have tried puting the methods from main as static methods still i cant call the methods this way ...If you could help me i would be appreciated ...

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Thanks for your time it was already been solved ... it was a problem of undestanding ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried puting the methods from main as static methods still i cant call the methods this way ...If you could help me i would be appreciated ...

Static methods are the last thing you should be using. It sounds like you want to have one object call the methods of another object, and to do that the first object must have a valid *reference* to the second object. This can be achieved by passing it through the first object's constructor parameter or via a setXXX(...) method.

For instance if the first object creates the second object, it could pass a reference to itself, `this` into the second object's parameter. e.g.,

The MainClass:

```
public class MainClass {
  private OtherClass otherClass;

  public MainClass() {
    otherClass = new OtherClass(this);
  }
}
```

the OtherClass:

```
public class OtherClass {
  public MainClass mainClass;

  public OtherClass(MainClass mainClass) {
    this.mainClass = mainClass;
  }

  public void someOtherClassMethod() {
     // now we can call methods with the MainClass reference
     mainClass.someMainClassMethod(); 
  }
}
```

For more details on your particular problem, consider telling us more about it and showing code.

Comment: I have a login form that was created using swing and is a indepedent class but the main method which has all the arraylist items which have the users.What i need is to get those users to check if the login is correct ...Thanks

Comment: @DestPT: Swing is simply a GUI library. If you want two objects to interact, you will need to pass references, pure and simple. For a simple example, please see the edit to my answer above.

Comment: it was a little confusing for me to understand it ... but thanks to you i could now understand that ... Thanks for your time